# How in #Python you can keep adding numbers automatically by hitting enter key

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to write a small #Pythonn code where an empty list keeps on getting appended through random integers as long as a user enter key.

I am thinking of using a while loop e.g. while intnum == 0 ==> intnum += random.append()

in my head, I can make it work but cannot get the syntax right :(

kindly assist.
Python Newbee

Comment: what is your exit condition? i.e when should it stop appending random fingers?

Comment: I am trying to make a game where one player goes for n number of time getting a total of int numbers. then the second one tries to beat that number. 0 is the termination from random numbers to kill the loop on each turn.

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure of what you want to achieve but try this for an idea:

```py
from random import seed, uniform
seed(1)
L = []
while True:
    input() # Enter is pressed
    L.append(round(uniform(0, 10), 2))   # a value from 0 to 10 with 2 decimal places
    print(L)
```